# Homotopy domination of a wedge of two polyhedra

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, polyhedra, cw-complexes

The topological space $A$ is called homotopy dominated by the space $X$ if there are maps $f:A\longrightarrow X$ and $g:X\longrightarrow A$ so that $g\circ f\simeq id_A$.

Question: Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two polyhedra.  If $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X_1\vee X_2$, then is $A$ of the form $A_1 \vee A_2$ (up to homotopy equivalent) where $A_i$ is homotopy dominated by $X_i$ for $i=1,2$?

Comment: Probably there is an example using the Wall finiteness obstruction. There are pairs of groups (probably including $(\mathbb Z/2,\mathbb Z/2)$) where the individual groups have no finiteness obstruction, but the free product does. Thus there exists a finitely dominated complex $A$ which is not finite whose fundamental group is a free product, but which is not a wedge of spaces with fundamental group the two factors, because those pieces $A_1,A_2$ would necessarily be finite, and thus $A_1\vee A_2$ would be finite. Something like $X_1=X_2=\mathbb RP^2\vee S^3$.

Comment: My previous comment doesn't work for that particular pair of groups. Also, it is too complicated, I guess because I didn't want to commit to a particular number of spheres or worry about a very simple space having a retract. Just take $X_1=S^2\vee S^2$ and $X_2=S^3/Q_8$. The wedge has a retract with nontrivial obstruction, but neither space does. $X_1$ doesn't because it is simply connected and $X_2$ doesn't because it is rationally irreducible. Or $X_2=S^3/(\mathbb Z/23)$ and maybe more spheres for $X_1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer here is certainly yes under many sets of mild side hypotheses.

For example, once upon a time, I wrote a paper with Frank Adams (!) that seems of some relevance: [J.F.Adams and N.J.Kuhn, *Atomic spaces and spectra*, Proc. Edin. Math. Soc **32** (1989), 473-481].  We show that if $X$ is a space or spectrum that is $p$--complete and of finite type, then the monoid of homotopy classes of based self maps $[X,X]$ is a profinite monoid. In this case, one concludes that, if $X$ has no nontrivial retracts then every self map is either invertible or topologically nilpotent.

Let's apply this to the stated question, under the hypotheses $A$ has no nontrivial retracts and is complete of finite type.  Consideration of homology shows that at least one of the two maps $A \rightarrow X \rightarrow X_i \rightarrow X \rightarrow A$ is not topologically nilpotent, and so must be an equivalence.  Thus $A$ is a retract of either $X_1$ or $X_2$, i.e. the question has an affirmative answer in this case.

More generally, you are asking something closely related to a Krull-Schmidt type theorem for spaces: if a space $X$ is written as a wedge of `indecomposable' spaces in two different ways, must the pieces correspond?  Issues here include: need a space be written in this way?  and also: What is the difference between retracts and wedge summands?

If $X_1 \vee X_2$ is a suspension, and suitably complete, then certainly a Krull-Schmidt theorem holds and the answer is yes.  In the more algebraic world of spectra, some of us were using these ideas all the time in the early 1980's in papers about stable splittings of classifying spaces.

Comment: Your answer gave me a lot of information. I learned some facts of your response.  Thank you so much for help specially your great paper.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit Mar. 2020*: My original post was more concerned with specific maps than general existence results. Since it perhaps missed the point here is a more worthwhile comment.

No. Let $\alpha$ generate $\pi_6S^3\cong\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and let $\beta=5\cdot\alpha$. Put
$$X=S^3\cup_\alpha e^7,\qquad Y=S^3\cup_\beta e^7.$$
Then $X,Y$ are compact polyhedra and
$$X\not\simeq Y.$$
In fact there is no map between these spaces which induces an isomorphism in homology. On the other hand
$$X\vee S^3\simeq (S^3\vee S^3)\cup_{(i_1\alpha +i_2\beta)} e^7\simeq Y\vee S^3.$$
Thus $X$ is dominated by $Y\vee S^3$. Clearly $X$ is wedge-indecomposable, but it is neither dominated by $Y$ or by $S^3$.

Replacing $X,Y$ with $\Sigma^nX$ and $\Sigma^n Y$ we obtain examples of suspensions and even stable homotopy types with the same behaviour.

Here is the original answer. *No. Take $A=S^n$ and $X=X_1\vee X_2=S^n\vee S^n$. Let $f=2\vee (-1):S^n\rightarrow S^n\vee S^n$ be the sum of the degree $2$- and degree $-1$-self maps included into each respective factor. Now take $g=\nabla:S^n\vee S^n\rightarrow S^n$ to be the fold map. Then $g\circ f\simeq 2-1\simeq 1\simeq id_{S^n}$ so $S^n$ is homotopy dominated by $S^n\vee S^n$. However $S^n$ is indecomposable.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Clearly, $\mathbb{S}^n$ is homotopy dominated by $\mathbb{S}^n \vee \mathbb{S}^n$ (even is a  retract of $\mathbb{S}^n \vee \mathbb{S}^n$) . But if $x$ is  the wedge point of $\mathbb{S}^n \vee \mathbb{S}^n$, then we can consider $\mathbb{S}^n$ itselt as the form $\mathbb{S}^n \vee \{ x\}$.

Comment: In line 4, two occurences of $S^7$ should be $e^7$; I lack the authority to edit.

Comment: @IJL corrected.

Comment: Shearing is an interesting idea, but... Aren't $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent? Isn't the key what subgroup the attaching map generates?

Comment: @BenWieland $X$ and $Y$ are not homotopy equivalent. Assume a homotopy equivalence $X\rightarrow Y$ and look at the induced maps between the Puppe sequences of the two complexes. You get degree $\pm1$ maps on $S^7$ and on $S^4=\Sigma S^3$. But no choice of signs is compatible with the suspensions of $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: I think this fits with my old comments as follows: $X$ and $Y$ will be equivalent localized away from 5 and also completed at 5 (when both will just be $S^3 \vee S^7$).  By the way, does $\beta = 5\alpha$ mean $\alpha \circ 5$ or $5 \circ \alpha$ in $\pi_6(S^3)$?  (Are these the same?)

Comment: @NicholasKuhn $\alpha\circ 5$ and $5\circ\alpha$ are the same in $\pi_6S^3$ by an Eckmann-Hilton argument. Normally I would understand $5\cdot\alpha=\alpha\circ 5$ for an element $\alpha\in\pi_nZ$. It seems to me that $X,Y$ will be actually be equivalent when localised at *any* prime.